# JavaScript: Method forEach not supported from Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, foreach

I'm using a javascript implementation of the gzip algorithm which works fine with Firefox and Chrome. But with Internet Explorer I got the following error:

> Method forEach is not supported!

**Code:**

```
deflate.deflate(data, level).forEach(function (byte) {
    putByte(byte, out);
});
```

I'm using Internet Explorer 9, which should support the forEach Method.

Any ideas?

Thank you very much!

Comment: forEach isn't supported in IE8. IE9 should support it, however. http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Array.prototype.forEach

Comment: Is your page running in quirks mode in IE? (Perhaps by accident?) `.forEach()` is only supported in standards mode. Does `deflate.deflate()` always return an array?

Comment: Rather than extending a built-in object, you can replace the `forEach` part with a 2 line `for` loop.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You might try and extend the `Array` object for browsers that don't support the `foreach` method on it as suggested here [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2FforEach#Compatibility)

One example is:

```
if (!Array.prototype.forEach) {
    Array.prototype.forEach = function(fn, scope) {
        for(var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; ++i) {
            fn.call(scope, this[i], i, this);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

forEach is not supported in IE9, you can try using jquery.
ex:

```
$. each (function (byte) {
  putByte(byte, out);
});
```

Comment: i want to avoid the usage of jquery.

Comment: I used jQuery as a work around and was happy with the result. $.eachdata.Emails, function( index, value ) {
 $('#lblEmails').append(value + " ");
});

Comment: Adding a full library and increase the page load time just to implement a for loop would not be good.