# Angular 4 IE 11 issue : not rendering a component multiple times in a page

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, internet-explorer, web-applications

I am currently facing an issue with IE 11 browser. I am building a web application using angular 4, and I have a requirement where I need to display a button twice in the page. This button is a component, and hence the page html will have this component mentioned twice.
In all other browsers I see the button is getting displayed twice. But in IE, only one button is rendered.
Seeing the console log I see there is a error thrown.

**object doesn't support property or method 'foreach'**

I feel this is the issue why the button is not displayed, I tried all the alternatives like adding all the necessary import in the polyfill.js, but didn't help.

Could someone please help on this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why I have this error: Object doesn't support property or method 'forEach' for Internet Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20098953/why-i-have-this-error-object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-foreach-for-i)

Comment: **[You might also wanna see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16813583/2065039)**

Answer (score 0):

If you used the Angular-CLI to generate your website then there should be a polyfills.ts. In that file you need to un-commonent the IE9, IE10, and IE11 pollyfill imports.