# Use a link ONLY when javascript is disabled

Tags: javascript, codeigniter-3, noscript

I have a social networking site for my college community and its working fine. There is a feature to like a post by other users. Liking is triggered using javascript's onClick() function.

Recently due to security reasons, many of our members disabled javascript.

Is there any way to redirect a user to a particular page if javascript is disabled? Otherwise the script should work.

For a more discriptive detail, assume my current code is like:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return likeFunction();">Item</a>
```

what i want is something like:

```
<a href="www.mysite.com/postController/likeAction" onclick="return likeFunction();">Like</a>
```

**but href should be active only if onclick() function dont work. is that possible? **

my site is built with php codeigniter. any solutions?

Comment: Add the correct link in every `<a>` tag, and in your JS, use `preventDefault()` to override the href

Comment: donno much with javascript. but guess <noscript></noscript> tags may be helpfull. lemme research and will let you know if i could help

Comment: Going off of what @WillardSolutions mentioned, you can also add `return false` in your function to override.

Comment: onclick is a very old fashioned way of attaching event handlers to HTML elements.  It's vastly preferable to add them programmatically with addEventListener (or a framework that wraps it).  By the way, this isn't a PHP question.  Please don't mistag questions.

Answer (score 2):

Just return false on the function that is called in the onClick event.
So either make sure that likeFunction() returns false. Or, return false afterwards with `onClick="likeFunction(); return false;"`.

In general, you should always put a link in the href and not rely exclusively on JS. An anchor tag should not be [abused with the onclick event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Accessibility_concerns) to create pseudo-buttons. You might consider using a button tag if no link has to be put in the href.

Also, the href should start with the protocol (`http://www.example.com` instead of `www.example.com`).

Side note: You might consider attaching the JS event by calling addEventListener instead of using the onClick attribute. There are different cons and pros using either methods. I suggest you to have a look at this answer: [addEventListener vs onclick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick).

Edit: As WillardSolutions suggested, you can use preventDefault to ensure the link is not opened when the onClick event is called. For further details, I suggest you to have a look at this answer: [event.preventDefault() vs. return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

Answer (score 1):

Don't muddy up your HTML, simply enhance it with JavaScript (see: [Progressive Enhancement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement)). This can be easily achieved with a CSS class and a document selector.

Given the HTML:

```
<a href="/postController/likeAction" class="like">Like</a>
```

You can add a self executing JavaScript function just before the `</body>` tag:

```
<script>
(function() {
    document.querySelectorAll('a.like').forEach(function(item) {
        item.removeAttribute('href');
        item.onclick = function() {
            /* add the likeFunction functionality here */
        };
    });
})();
</script>
```

That's pretty basic; it loops through all `<a>` tags that have `class="like"`, removes the `href` attribute and adds the functionality from your current `likeFunction()` to the click event (if you copy the code from the `likeFunction()` to where indicated).

Obviously if JavaScript is disabled, the DOM isn't updated and your original HTML remains in place.

---

**Note:** `forEach()` support may be [sketchy in Microsoft browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16813469/javascript-method-foreach-not-supported-from-internet-explorer).

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use [`preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

```
// if js is disabled, this doesn't execute at all, 
// so the link will work by default and take the user to the url defined inside the `href` tag.
document.getElementById('myLink').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault(); // This will tell the browser not to follow the link.

    ... Do Awesome stuff here all day long

});
```

[**DEMO**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LXeZYY)